# Can people modify/create cookies on my websites domain?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, web

I have a website and am making a login system using cookies so the user can stay logged in, which I believe you can't do with sessions. I wanted to know if a malicious user could create or modify the existing cookies on the domain. I know they can delete them, that's fine, but can they create or modify them?

Comment: Editing/creating cookies is extremely easy to do, you'd be better off doing this with php sessions. the session will stay active until the user clears their cookies or you use the `session_destroy();` function

Comment: Of course.  You can never trust any data that comes from the client.

Comment: @HarrisonPickering what do you mean "I believe you can't do with sessions" You can do with sessions and should do with sessions.

Comment: Since you're creating a login system [don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: Usually this is done by creating a cookie client side that equals the hashed password/username of the user that wants to stay logged in, then if he visits the website again the website checks if he has this cookie and checks if the value of the cookie allows him to login with said username and password stored in the cookie. This way, malicious users can create cookies all they want but without the password they can't get access. Beware of session hijacking though.

Comment: @JameyD: Sending a hashed password to the client is a bad idea.  Sessions should be signed, random, revocable tokens.

Comment: The short answer is yes - the slightly longer answer is that it might not even be the same user or machine... cookie hijacking on Starbucks public wifi for instance.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. I will take this information into account for my login system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone can control their browser, however they like.  They can create, edit and delete cookies.

For that reason, your cookies should be long and random (or at least random-looking to the point of being indistinguishable from random).

They should be meaningful to your server, which should be able to relate them to a user, but not meaningful to anyone outside your server.  They should be long enough and complex enough that guessing one would be statistically impossible.

Your server should be careful not to make any assumptions about the cookie values it receives.  For instance, I could submit a cookie with 2,000 characters in it - that mustn't cause it to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can create, delete and edit your browser cookies, everyone who have access to your computer can read them, and copy so you can steal session ID for example.

You cannot modify session manually, because this is "server cookie", only server software can do it. If you want store password or other secret information, you should not store it inside cookie. Its insecure, you can store token or session id but not inforamtion like password.